key does not identify an element in this collection value in terraform
I am getting below error while provision the servicebus topic subscription. can some one help me to figure this out.
Module code :
resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "subscription" {
  for_each            = { for sb in var.topic_list : "${sb["subscription"]}" => sb }
  name                = each.value["subscription"]
  topic_id            = azurerm_servicebus_topic.topics["${each.value.name}"].id
  max_delivery_count  = var.max_delivery_count
}

variable.tf:
variable "topic_list" {
  type = list(object({
    name                    = string
    max_size_in_megabytes   = string
  }))
  default     = []
}

Inputs values:
topic_list: 
  - name: "topicair"
    max_size_in_megabytes: "5120"
    subscriptions: 
      - subscription: subscription1
      - subscription: subscription2
      - subscription: subscription3
  - name: "topicwint"
    max_size_in_megabytes: "81920"
    subscriptions: 
      - subscription: subscriptiontop1
      - subscription: subscriptiontop2
      - subscription: subscriptiontop3

Error :
Error: Invalid index
│
│   on .terraform\modules\servicebus\modules\servicebus\main.tf line 103, in resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "subscription":
│  103:   for_each            = { for sb in var.topic_list : "${sb["subscription"]}" => sb }
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on .terraform\modules\servicebus\modules\servicebus\main.tf line 103, in resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "subscription":
│  103:   for_each            = { for sb in var.topic_list : "${sb["subscription"]}" => sb }
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.


The error occurs because your Terraform code tries to access a subscription key in each item of the topic_list, which doesn't exist directly. Instead, each topic item contains a subscriptions list.
So you need to adjust your for_each to correctly iterate through each subscription in the nested subscriptions list for every topic.
This is how I’ll update your Terraform code to fix this:

resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "subscription" {
  for_each = { 
    for topic in var.topic_list : 
      for sub in topic.subscriptions : 
        "${topic.name}-${sub.subscription}" => {
          topic_name    = topic.name,
          subscription  = sub.subscription
        }
  }
  
  name                = each.value.subscription
  topic_id            = azurerm_servicebus_topic.topics[each.value.topic_name].id
  max_delivery_count  = var.max_delivery_count
}


These changes will correctly generate subscription resources for each subscription in your topic_list under the appropriate topic. Run terraform plan after updating to ensure that the configurations look good.
Ensure azurerm_servicebus_topic.topics is indeed set up to map topic names to topic IDs as expected.
Hope this helps.

tried but getting error
Error: Invalid 'for' expression
Key expression is required when building an object.
110:   for_each = {
│  111:     for topic in var.topic_list :
│  112:       for sub in topic.subscriptions :
│  113:         "${topic.name}-${sub.subscription}" => {
│  114:           topic_name      = topic.name
│  115:           subscription    = sub.subscription
│  116:         }
│  117:   }
│

this error too
110:   for_each = {
│  111:     for topic in var.topic_list :
│  112:       for sub in topic.subscriptions :
│
│ Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression.
